# 403 error when using fineUploader to upload directly to S3 with no server side code

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I followed this tutorial http://blog.fineuploader.com/2014/01/15/uploads-without-any-server-code/ and am making good progress, but i'm stumped again.

Here is the CORS policy for my bucket (i'm assuming this is where the error is):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://www.xxxdomainxxx.fr</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>content-type</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>origin</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>x-amz-acl</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>x-amz-meta-qqfilename</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>x-amz-date</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>authorization</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>x-amz-security-token</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

The upload goes fine (I see the progress bar) and it goes through the entire file, but at the end of the upload, the UI switches to "processing" and then i get an "access denied" message and no file is in the bucket. The console printed:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) (xxxxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com, line 0)

I'm getting a 403 error back from AWS and i'm not sure how to debug this. See anything missing?

Thanks for any pointers.

## **Update 1**

I figured i'd try with a dumb down version of the CORS file to start with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

But i'm getting the same error. 
Here is the failing POST request:

```
key test test/c8491b98-284a-4d5d-90d4-f6ec7151bc1d.diff
AWSAccessKeyId  XXXXXXXXXXX
success_action_status   200
x-amz-security-token    XXXXXXXX
acl public-read
x-amz-meta-qqfilename   opentok.diff
policy  XXXXXX
signature   XXXXXXX
file    opentok.diff
```

And the response

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods    GET, POST, PUT
Access-Control-Max-Age  3000
Vary    Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
x-amz-request-id    8B619A5A96A954F6
x-amz-id-2  ZUPdtFRIdSKDK0ealKUKUCtHDW3GkNU5ZVZPDxlXPi/9J2oZiNcV3TltougJuhXnzY/BlbZrc1c=
Content-Type    application/xml
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Date    Wed, 07 Oct 2015 08:11:24 GMT
Server  AmazonS3
```

Comment: Which request is failing?

Comment: @RayNicholus Details added to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not with the CORS configuration, but with the policy used for the bucket. The resource string was

```
arn:was:s3:::bucketName
```

and needed to be

```
arn:was:s3:::bucketName/*
```

The devil is in the details as usual...